# jQuery datepicker not displaying value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a field for inputting an employee's hire date that uses a jQuery datepicker, which works perfect. However, when you edit this employee's information the hire date field displays mm/dd/yyyy, but viewing the html shows the correct hire date value from the database. I implemented my datepicker using an editor template.

Generated HTML:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Hire Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Hire Date field is required." id="HireDate" name="HireDate" type="date" value="02/12/89">
```

Editor Template:

```
 @Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HireDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HireDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HireDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

I have tried multiple variation of dateformat in the JS, but nothing seems to be working. What can I do to display the existing date?

Comment: Do you have a code behind file?

Comment: No I'm not using any custom code behind file. I've updated my post to show the complete code in this section of the view.

Comment: When you say "dateformat in the JS", did you mean you tried `$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });`? Although if you are refreshing the page on submits, the value that should be coming from the model is going to be in the "mm/dd/yyyy" format as you've specified in the TextBox. Also, consider using `Html.TextBoxFor(yourmodel => yourmodel.DateValue, params)` if the date is already in the correct format from your database.

Comment: `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });` should work. You could also try `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HireDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})` instead or `EditorFor` so it does not add the `type="date"` attribute

Comment: What is your Editor template view name?

Comment: @VenkataPanga the Editor template name is Date.cshtml

Comment: @StephenMuecke using ...{dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'} did not work. However, using "@Html.TextBoxFor" did work, but it results in a different datepicker coming up. Is there a way to make it use the same datepicker as the editorfor is using on other pages to make the site consistent?

Comment: @user2325484, `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HireDate, "{0:dd/MM/yy}", new { @class = "datepicker"})` should do the trick.

Comment: the view name must be DateTime.cshtml or otherwise you should supply "Date" from EditorFor, I've added answer with details, please check

Comment: @user2325484, When you use `EditorFor()` it adds `type="date"` and by default this will use the browser's datepicker implementation (which requires a date to be formatted as `"yyyy-MM-dd"` - although there does seem to be possible variations depending on the browser). I suspect there must then some conflict when you then attach the jqueryUI datepicker. `TextBoxFor()` will add `type="text"` so the browser just renders a normal textbox. Then you can attach the plugin using `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided markup should show the value, there would be something else to understand.

The rendered HTML

```
<input class="text-box single-line" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-date="The field Hire Date must be a date." 
    data-val-required="The Hire Date field is required." 
    id="HireDate" name="HireDate" 
    type="date" 
    value="02/12/89" 
/>
```

Here we can notice that the generated html for the element doesn't has css class = `datepicker` which we specify in view level(high precedence, supplied editor for css class will get override with view level class they cant merge together).

`value="02/12/89"` indicates that you've decorated with  `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="MM/dd/yy")]` at Model Property `HideDate`

Now, it tells that control not rendering from its EditorTemplates view, it was rendering based on datatype with defaults as html5 `input` element with `type=date` and with `placeholder` as `mm/dd/yyyy`

Here we need to make sure that the naming conventions for EditorTemplates folder name and the view name.
Editor-Template View path would look like
`..\Views\[Shared|ControllerName]\EditorTemplates\[DataType|CustomName].cshtml`

**Your Editor Template Path must be one of below two cases**
In your case data-type = `DateTime`
So default view path would look like `..\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`

If your controller name is `Employee` the controller specific template path would be `..\Views\Employee\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`

**Your Case**
If you're using custom name like `Date.cshtml` that you mentioned in comments then
path should be `..\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.cshtml`

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

and from `EditorFor` you should pass view name like  below

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HireDate, "Date")
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you for providing all the details. This was the first time I had used an Editor Template.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the overload with format parameter

```
HtmlHelper.TextBox(string name, objeect value, string format, object htmlAttributes)
```

for examaple:

```
@Html.TextBox("", Model,"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

Comment: I tried adding in the format parameter, but it still only displays the placeholder text instead of the correct date value.